# MySQL Subquery in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first question. I've trying to deal with this all week long with no success.

I have the following table

```
ID F1   F2
1   1   10
2   3    5
3   2    8
4   7   10
5  11   20
6  12   18
7  15   20
```

Please note that the values of the rows 2,3,4 are between the values of the first row.

Then, rows 6 and 7 are between the values of the row 5

I need to create a query that should bring me only rows 1 and 5.

I have tried many kind of queries with no success.

I was expecting the following query to work (among many others) but it did not.

```
select OL.F1,OL.F2
from borrar OL,
 (select F1,F2
 from borrar
  ) IL
where
OL.F1 >= IL.F1
and OL.F2 <= IL.F2
```

Any ideas?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self-join.  The thing that makes rows 1 and 5 different from the other rows is that there are no rows in the table where F1 is less than Row 1&5's value for F1 and F2  is greater than Row 1&5's value for F2.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM datatable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN datatable t2
on t2.F1<=t1.F1 and t2.F2>=t1.F2 and t1.id<>t2.id
WHERE t2.ID is NULL
```

Self joins are always a bit confusing.  Each row is combined with all other rows to find if there is some other row that "spans" it (i.e. F1 and F2 are equal to or outside it) but need to exclude the row spanning itself.  Use an outer join, and search for NULL's to find the rows that have no matches.

Comment: second sentence is a bit confusing at the end, what is it trying to say?

Comment: Thanks.  I used a "less than" sign and it was not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework problem...

But, one thing I noticed is that F2-F1 = 9 in both cases. Perhaps using that in the Where clause will do the trick ;)

Comment: Hi CKP.., I wish it would be a homework problem, it would mean I'm much younger which is not the case. The real problem is different but the "backend" is the same. In this case you are right f2-f1 is 9 but the true is that the table has over 15.000 records growing daily, I'm working with many many more numbers. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. I will think about it a little more and see what I can come up with. Sorry I jumped to conclusions!

Comment: Can you give more context? Are you looking only for rows where there are subsequent rows with F1 and F2 values between it? Thats what I understand the question to be.

Comment: Sure. I don't want the query to return values between (based in the example) 1-10 and 11-20. So, the query should be able to determine that there are many rows that have values in the middle and do not return them.  Note that that in the example 2,3,4,6 and 7 are values that are already covered by rows 1 and 5